# Google API PHP CLient and __Secure-XXX session name

Tags: php, security, nginx, session-cookies, google-api-php-client

i have a web app that let users to send there appointment from the calendar in the webapp to google calendar.

To make it, i connect users to their google profile with oauth2 within the webapp:

1. User click on "Connect to google",
2. and the process of Google to select the google account and autorise my app start.
3. User click on "Autorise" and i redirect to my webapp through https://example.com/oauth2callback

It works fine.

But we wanted to improve safety based on what mozilla observatory offers. We added this before "session_start".

```
session_name('__Secure-PHPSESSID');
session_set_cookie_params([
    'lifetime' => 7000,
    'secure' => true,
    'httponly' => true,
    'samesite' => 'strict',
]);
session_start();
```

Since then, each time my new users try to connect to their google account, the process start but when they click on "Autorise" my URL: https://example.com/oauth2callback lost the session and my users need to authenticate to my webapp and nothing happen with Google. If i remove the code above and keep session_start(); it works.

Do you think google api php client can't converse with my server or is it my server config (i'm on nginx) ?

EDIT:
so as marek propose in comments, i tested this code:

```
session_name('__Secure-PHPSESSID');
session_set_cookie_params([
    'lifetime' => 7000,
    'secure' => true,
    'httponly' => true,
    //'samesite' => 'Strict',
]);
session_start();
```

But it doesn't work. I tried to comment each line of session_set_cookie_params. Same thing it doesn't work. I tried to comment all session_set_cookie_params, same thing.

It's only works when session_start is the first line.

FOUND A SOLUTION:
juste replace:
'samesite' => 'strict',
by
'samesite' => 'lax',

Comment: Can you temporary remove only `'samesite' => 'strict',` and check if it works then?

Comment: @MarekPuchalski Sorry i deleted my previous message in which i told you it works. Actually it doesn't work. I let session_start() at the first line so session_set_cookie_params wasn't take. I edit my question